# VBA with Excel eliminating human error

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet I am trying to setup some code so when a user changes field E13 a reminder comes up highlighting fields E19, E29, E31, E39, E41.  E13 is a change order field with a money value and I want users to know they need to address the other fields once they change E13. I want the cells to be highlighted if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim E13 As Range, rFix As Range
    Set E13 = Range("E13")
    Set rFix = Range("E19,E29,E31,E39,E41")
    If Intersect(E13, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        rFix.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        MsgBox "Please update the hi-lighted cells and remove the hi-lighting"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: + 1 :) You might also wanna see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)... the 3rd point... since you are using worksheet_change